# Why doesn't my command work when aliased?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, alias

I use `ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep` to print the tomcat process running on the system:

```
kshitiz   7099     1  0 May11 ?        00:02:29 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:38156 -Dcatalina.base=/home/kshitiz/Documents/workspaces/ggts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat-7.0.42 -Dwtp.deploy=/home/kshitiz/Documents/workspaces/ggts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat-7.0.42/endorsed -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/tomcat-7.0.42/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/lib/tools.jar org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Then I use `ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'` to extract the process id:

```
7099
```

But when I alias the whole command `alias tomcat_id="ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'"` and use it via alias, it prints the whole text and `awk` doesn't seem to work.

`type tomcat_id` gives:

```
tomcat_id is aliased to `ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep | awk -F' ' '{print }''
```

Comment: You might want to look at using `pgrep` if your system supports it - or, failing that, doing the match in awk to save the extra calls to grep. If you *must* use grep, there's a regex trick `grep [c]atalina` that should allow you to remove the `grep -v grep` (which you can also use in awk for the same reason i.e. `awk '/[c]atalina/ {print \$2}'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general rule of aliases: if it gets too complex for an alias, use a function instead.

```
tomcat_id () {
  ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
}
```

The problem with your alias definition is that you got the quoting wrong. The line that defines the alias is a shell command and is parsed by the shell. Since you used double quotes, and there are probably no positional parameters at the time (so `$2` expands to an empty string), the alias you've defined is

```
ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep | awk -F' ' '{print }'
```

The easy way to define an alias is to use single quotes for the definition, and avoid using single quotes in the aliased command. While I'm at it, I've removed `-F " "`, which is the default anyway (and a bit weird because it looks like “a space” but means “any sequence of whitespace”).

```
alias tomcat_id='ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep | awk "{print \$2}"'
```

Or you can use `'\''` to effectively quote a single quote inside a single-quoted literal.

```
alias tomcat_id='ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep | awk '\''{print \$2}'\'
```

But, as I wrote above, use a function, it's clearer. Or rather, use the appropriate tool for the job:

```
alias tomcat_id='pgrep catalina'
```

or

```
alias tomcat_id='pidof catalina'
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to make a command into an alias without a deep understanding of the command when the command already contains both single and double quotes?

Answer (score 3):

Gnouc's answer is perfectly valid (which is why I upvoted it), but I'd like to offer an alternative:

```
alias tomcat_id="ps -ef|awk '\$8 ~ /java/ && /catalina/ {print \$2}'"
```

the idea here is that in the process name (field 8) we should be able to find `java` and on the line as a whole we should find `catalina`.

So we let `awk` do all the work of matching and printing. No need to bother `grep` ;)

So the meaning:

```
$8 ~ /java/ && /catalina/ {print $2}
```

is match field `$8` against regex `/java/` and match the whole line (could also use `$0` explicitly) against regex `/catalina/` and if those things are true, print field `$2`. Remember what was already stated in Gnouc's answer: the default separator is a blank space already. No need to define this.

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the dollar sign in `awk` command:

```
alias tomcat_id="ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'"
```

And you don't have to use `-F' '`, `awk` use spaces as default field separate.