# Conditional Git alias within zsh: "parse error: condition expected: cd"

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, git, alias

I'm trying to implement a simple stack of git-related aliases for my personal dotfiles.

```
alias gs="[[ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree &> /dev/null) ]] || cd $D && git status -s"
-------------
$ gs
zsh: parse error: condition expected: cd
```

My logic (which I'm sure is flawed):

- If not within a Git work-tree, `cd $D` (`ENV var = my dotfile path`) and keep output to yourself :)
- Run `git status -s`

Reasoning: 90% of my git activity is to my personal repo. Being able to run `gs` (`gc` -> `git commit -m $*` via a function, `ga` -> `git add` , etc.) anywhere is very handy.

When intentionally working within another repo, I don't want to be automatically `cd`'ed to my dotfile path.

The command works outside the confines of an alias, but not within one. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried a few variations such as this, without output redirects:

```
alias gs="[[ $(git -C $(pwd) rev-parse) ]] || cd ${D} && git status -s"
```

Upon launching of the terminal with the alias above:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

**EDIT:** I successfully converted these aliases into working functions, but I would still like to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Variables are expanded immediately when in double quotes.

Comment: If I directly run `git status -s`, I also receive `fatal: not a git repository`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Should I convert it to a function? I'm going to give that a try.

Comment: No, just use single quotes in place of the double ones you're using around the alias now.

Comment: Your issue is also similar to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516172/different-output-when-alias  and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128995/why-doesnt-my-command-work-when-aliased and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163185/an-alias-for-a-command-to-kill-stopped-jobs

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you! Going forward, is the use single quoted aliases the best practice? Is my understanding correct here: When .zshrc sources my alias.zsh file, all variables and subshell commands are executed immediately? If I have nested `' cmd('x')'`, is escaping them all I need to do? This clears up countless "oddities" in the past that I couldn't troubleshoot. You're a peach.

Comment: You can't say "always use single quotes for aliases". You _can_ say, "use single quotes when you don't want the shell to expand things (command substitutions, variables) in the string".  You will need to understand the difference between double and single quoted strings, and then decide when you want to use which. There are absolutely situations where one may want to, or need to, create an alias using double quotes (possibly because part of the alias needs to be filled out using a variable).